# Searching for the right partitions

Tags: optimization, integer-partitions, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I have a set of integers $U$ with cardinality $311$ and whose sum is 500 dollars.

I want to group all the elements of this set into three different subsets:

- The sum of the elements of subset $A$ is $450$ dollars.
- The sum of the elements of subset $B$ is $30$ dollars.
- The sum of the elements of subset $C$ is $20$ dollars.

What kind of algorithm could provide me a way to find the correct partitions?

What kind of tool could I use to find the vectors of solution? MS Excel is not capable of solving so many decision variables, even if they're integers. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have a decision problem or an optimization problem? In other words, do you want to determine whether such a partition even exists, or do you want to find the possible partition that is closest to the desired one?

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=(450,30,20)$. Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether element $i$ appears in set $j$.  The constraints are:
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\sum_i i x_{i,j} &= b_j &&\text{for all $j$}
\end{align}